# Windows 10 File Renaming Tricks

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

I have a folder directory with media files where the folder structure is:

```
/Media Directory/Parent Directory/Files
```

Sorta two questions:

1. The naming convention of the Parent Directory is (year) title and I'd like to rename the files in each directory to match. Are there any tips for doing this?
2. Is there a way to pull metrics for the files in the media directory. Something that shows the count of different file types? I have a mix of mkv, mp4, and a few others. I'd like to convert all files to MP4.

Answer (score 0):

1.

You can use a renaming tool such as [ReNamer](https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer) to rename subfolders with text from the parent folder.

The Lite version of ReNamer is free and allows 5 renaming rules, but you will need only one for what you intent to do. ([Documentation](https://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer))

Under `[Filter Settings][3]`, tick `Add folders as files`.

Drag and drop all the parent folder into the "Drag your files here" window.

Add a new renaming rule by clicking on "Add" or double clicking on "Click here to add a rule". Use `Insert` rule with `Prefix` option and [insert metatag](https://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Meta_Tags) with the path function to add the folder name of the parent directory to the files.

[Preview](https://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Previewing_files) the results and rename.

2.

You can do this in windows explorer.

Go to the media directory and click on the search box and type a fullstop `.`

Windows explorer should list all the files and subfolders in media directory.
`Right click` on empty space and use `Group by` **Type** option to get the count of different file types. - [Example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1963993&seqNum=15)

Answer (score 0):

You have two great reasons to learn a little **PowerShell**! While there are various niche utilities, most of the time, what they do can also be done in **PowerShell**. And what you learn in **PowerShell** can serve you down the road.

[**Get-ChildItem**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) is the first *cmdlet* to learn. It's similar to '**Dir**' in **Command Prompt**. Combined with the [Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6) cmdlet, you can accomplish your first task with code something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\media directory' -file -recurse |
   Foreach-Object{
      $NewName = '({0:yyyy}) {1}' -f $_.CreationTime, $_.Name
      Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

-WhatIf will preview action without makig changes.
Though I doubt that's the year you want to use. You probably want to retrieve metadata from the media files, which is a little tricker ---but we can get you there.

For a count of all the various file types:

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\media directory' -file -recurse | Group extension
```

For working iteractively in the console, `Get-ChildItem` has the alias `gci`

Comment: "Naming convention of the Parent Directory is (year) title and I'd like to rename the files in each directory to match" - I think year (and name) from parent director's name need to be used, not creation year.